# Slicing a slice

Tags: go, slice

**Problem description:**
I've a slice `bar`. I want to create another slice `foo` with the first two elements of bar if there're at least 2 elements in `bar`. Or with the first element of `bar` if `bar` has at least one element.

The idea I had:

```
// bar := []int{1, 2, 3...
foo := bar[:(int)(math.Min(float64(len(bar)), 2))]
```

**EDIT:**
Here's another way I tried,

```
x := 2
if len(bar) < 2 {
    x = len(bar)
}
foo := bar[:x]
```

Is it possible to improve the code? At least, casting twice to achieve something so simple doesn't look good to me.

Comment: In your edit, you should change the 2 in the if condition to be x. That form is the simplest and probably most [idiomatic](http://golang.org/doc/faq#Does_Go_have_a_ternary_form).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the length of your slice is **greater than 2**, you can reslice it. If not, **no need to reslice just use the slice itself** in assignment which will automatically satisfy your needs: result will have up to a maximum of 2 elements.

You can even "spare" the `else` branch of the `if`:

```
foo := bar
if len(foo) > 2 {
    foo = foo[:2]
}
```

**Note:**

Slices are reference types. So even though you used `bar` to initialize `foo`, if you modify the `foo` *variable* afterwards (not the elements of the slice), that does not affect `bar` (the reference value is copied when assigned):

```
bar := []int{0, 1, 2, 3}
foo := bar
if len(foo) > 2 {
    foo = foo[:2]
}
fmt.Println(foo) // Here foo is [0, 1] as expected

foo = foo[:1]    // Reslicing foo
fmt.Println(bar) // Bar is unaffected, bar = [0 1 2 3]
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/ghVqsqPAYm)):

```
[0 1]
[0 1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use an `if`. It's much more readable and performant, since there is no conversion between `int` and `float64`.

```
var foo []int
if len(bar) > 1 {
    foo = bar[:2]
} else {
    foo = bar[:len(bar)]
}
```

Comment: I've thought about this too but this one is not very general. As instead of 2 if the upper bound was `X` then we would have to run a for loop to do so.

Comment: Maybe a switch base on `len(bar)` is better. if `bar` is empty its will a out of range panic.

Comment: @Fallen, @ANIsus see edit. I've used `len` in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Go does not have a `math.MinInt`. But implementing one is as simple as:

```
func Min(x, y int) int {
    if x < y {
        return x
    }
    return y
}

...

foo := bar[:Min(len(bar), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bar := []int{}
n := len(bar)
if n > 2 {
    n = 2
}
foo := bar[:n]
fmt.Printf("%v", foo)
```

Works with len(bar) = 0, 1, 2, n.. [Playground sample](https://play.golang.org/p/n_FsaIOblc)

Answer (score 0):

General (as you ask in a comment) function for arbitrary number of elements:

```
func strip(s []int, n int) []int {
    if len(s) < n {
        n = len(s)
    }
    return s[:n]
}

...
foo := strip(bar, 2)
```

[Go Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/6vqkgrmcc_)